# Error Subdataset with "One empty Record"

Tags: jasper-reports, datasource, classcastexception

I want to see a report with all the fields empty but without a source, so i have to do it with "One empty Record". The main problem is that whatever i do, if there is a JRXmlDataSource in the code that i put in the JRDatasource expression, it will throw me an error if i put "One empty Record" as datasource.

[image: JRDatasource expression screenshot]

Here is the code:

```
IF($P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}.toString().toLowerCase().contains("net.sf.jasperreports.engine.jremptydatasource"),new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JREmptyDataSource(),((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRXmlDataSource)$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}).subDataSource("SOME XPATH HERE"))
```

I've been looking all day but all the things i do go to the same exact point.

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JREmptyDataSource cannot be cast to net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRXmlDataSource
```

Comment: Added all the code from the picture, i forgot it sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check that `$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}` is subclass of `net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JREmptyDataSource` of not.

The valid expression in your case will be:

```
<dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[IF(($P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE} instanceof net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JREmptyDataSource), new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JREmptyDataSource(), ((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRXmlDataSource) $P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}).subDataSource("SOME XPATH HERE"))]]></dataSourceExpression>
```

For example this Java code will work with *jrxml* below:

```
Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
//params.put("REPORT_DATA_SOURCE", new JRXmlDataSource("customers.xml", "/Customers/*")); // this is working expression also
params.put("REPORT_DATA_SOURCE", new JREmptyDataSource(1)); // one record dataset 

JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, params, dataSource);
```

Template:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Report with check of datasource" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20">
    <parameter name="REPORT_DATASOURCE" class="java.lang.Object"/>
    <field name="id" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[child::text()]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <variable name="expression" class="java.lang.String">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA["/Customers/Customer[CustomerID='" + $F{id} + "']"]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
    <detail>
        <band height="70" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="100" y="0" width="100" height="15"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{id}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="15"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Id:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <subreport>
                <reportElement x="54" y="15" width="380" height="45"/>
                <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[IF(($P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE} instanceof net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JREmptyDataSource), new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JREmptyDataSource(), ((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRXmlDataSource) $P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}).subDataSource("SOME XPATH HERE"))]]></dataSourceExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA["./jrxml/subreport_with_xml.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

Comment: I did solve it with part of your code and a little change.

I finally used the ternary operator which i didn´t know about. And it does what i want to. It doesn't evaluate code that it is not in the condition it has to evaluate, so it doesn't throw me error messages and it evaluates good so it does the thing.

$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE} instanceof net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JREmptyDataSource?new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JREmptyDataSource(2):((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRXmlDataSource)$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}).subDataSource("SOME XPATH CODE")